# Is there a way to filter live streaming data in the Power BI Service

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi

We have IoT Data being streamed to the PowerBI Service (from Azure Stream Analytics).  We would like to do filtering of this live streaming data - so that the user can view data for a certain IoT device (or machine) only.

It seems that PowerBI Reports allow filtering and drill-through but NOT dashboards.  And Reports are not meant for streaming data.  They do not auto-refresh.

I looked on AppSource for possible visuals that may be used.  There is an Attribute Slicer visual but it seems to be for Reports - not dashboards.

1. **Any recommendations for how to enable filtering - of this streaming data - on the dashboard?**
2. **Is a custom visual needed (using PowerBI SDK and/or PowerBI API's)?**
3. **Any other options?**

One option is to have a simple HTML page with a drop down list that has the link for separate PowerBI dashboards per IoT device (a separate dashboard for each device).  It is not the best solution.

Thanks.